# How to get DataTemplate.DataTrigger to check for greater than or less than?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datatrigger

The following `DataTemplate.DataTrigger` makes the age display red if it is **equal to** 30.

How do I make the age display red if it is **greater than** 30?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Style="{StaticResource customerGridMainStyle}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="First Name" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Last Name" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Age" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Age" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age}">
            <DataTrigger.Value>30</DataTrigger.Value>
            <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>

</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could create an `IValueConverter`, which converts an integer to a boolean based on the `CutOff`. Then use `DataTrigger.Value` of `True` (or `False`, depending on what you are returning).

WPF `DataTrigger`s are strictly equality comparers if I remember correctly.

So something similar to:

```
public class CutoffConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return ((int)value) > Cutoff;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Cutoff { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the following XAML.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myNamespace:CutoffConverter x:Key="AgeConverter" Cutoff="30" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age,
                                   Converter={StaticResource AgeConverter}}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>true</DataTrigger.Value>
        <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: alternatively you can use ConverterParameter to pass in the cutoff value if you need different values for different triggers:
Binding="{Binding Path=Age, Converter={StaticResource AgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=30}"

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend using an `IValueConverter` to bind to the `Foreground` element of the Age `TextBlock` and isolating the coloring logic there.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Age"  
           Text="{Binding Age}" 
           Foreground="{Binding Path=Age, Converter={StaticResource AgeToColorConverter}}" />
```

Then in the Code:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
public class AgeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type target)
   {
      int age;
      Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), age);
      return (age >= 30 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe there is a simpler way of acheiving the goal by using the powers of MVVM and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

---

With the `Age` property create another property which will be a boolean called `IsAgeValid`. The `IsAgeValid` will simply be an *on demand* check which does not *technically* need an the `OnNotify` call. How?

To get changes pushed to the Xaml, place the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` event to be fired for `IsAgeValid` **within** the `Age` setter instead.

Any binding to `IsAgeValid` will *also* have a notify message sent on any `Age` change subscriptions; which is what really is being looked at...

---

Once setup, of course bind the style trigger for false and true accordingly to the `IsAgeValid` result.

```
public bool IsAgeValid{ get { return Age > 30; } }

public int Age
{ 
  get { return _Age; }

  set
  {
   _Age=value;
   OnPropertyChanged("Age");   
   OnPropertyChanged("IsAgeValid"); // When age changes, so does the
                                    // question *is age valid* changes. So 
                                    // update the controls dependent on it.
   } 
 }
```

Comment: This should be the answer for this specific example. Where possible control properties that represent real business logic should be provided to the view through a ViewModel, not 'view side'. This allows values to be configured through configuration/database etc.

Comment: @TomDeloford Having the business logic on the VM, makes sense to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you could add a property to your model, that's the easiest way.
Eg.

```
public int AgeBoundry
{
    get
    {
        if (Age < 30)
            return 0;
        else if (Age == 30)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
}
```

then you can check on the value of the integer.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>0</DataTrigger.Value>
        <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>1</DataTrigger.Value>
        <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age}">
        <DataTrigger.Value>2</DataTrigger.Value>
        <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Where does `Ageboundry` come into effect on the triggers? Instead of binding to `Age`, shouldn't it be `AgeBoundary`?