# WPF "Coloured binding"

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, label

I have few labels I use for displaying results.

Basically, they display numbers in following format

```
string.Format("{0:0.#}", number)
```

Their `Text` property is binded to objects. Result should be plus or minus signed.

Is there a way to set `Foreground` property of label according to result sign? For example green plus results and red minus results?

Comment: Check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793926/how-to-get-datatemplate-datatrigger-to-check-for-greater-than-or-less-than.

Comment: Thx, but no need to vote down. I searched for similar question, but did't know about triggers hance I can't found anything.

Comment: I voted up, I really don't understand why somebody voted down on this post. Go this Erno's answer. It is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Ucodia Thank you, I already did it sice Trigger can't do the job.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.

Comment: It was not me who voted down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to add a ValueConverter that transforms the value to a brush. 
Bind the value to the Foreground property using the converter.

[Here is an example](http://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2007/07/15/wpf-using-ivalueconverter/)

**EDIT**
Another option would be to add an extra property to the object you are binding to.
The property would be a Brush that changes with the number to the correct color.
Then just bind the Foreground to the property. This approach is common in MVVM.

Comment: I added another option to my answer.