# Theming a single element differently than it's siblings

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I have a datagrid where the I have overridden the row style and control template for some custom theming. For the sake of example, I have put a rectangle (height: 1, fill: red) above each row. Like the image on the left here -

[image]

Here is the control template that does this, I have simply added a red rectangle to the default template.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            **<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Red" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>**
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="3" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

But say I want it to look like the image on the right...where there is no red rectangle for the first row. How would I go about doing that?

I have run into this issue a few times since while Ive been theming with WPF - I have another issue with TabItem Headers, in that I need the first tab to look differently than the rest. With CSS or jquery there are selectors specifically for this purpose when working on websites. Im writing a WPF desktop application and I can't see how to do it from a xaml/C# perspective. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) with a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) on [`PreviousData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx), if it is `null` you have the first row.

*(**Note:** If you do the same thing in a style targeting `DataGridCells` the `PreviousData` will work by column (as the previous cell is in the previous column), so the same trigger will affect the whole first column rather than the first row)*

Answer (score 1):

Just change BorderThickness like this.

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Red"/>
```

Comment: That workaround won't work for what I need to do. I didnt want to make the example too awkward too read so I simplified it a bit. But I have to be able to style the first element in a group of elements differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some sort of trigger. something like this (havent tested it):
(edited: try the datatrigger on the datagrid)

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.Row" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: That will set the BorderThickness and BorderBrush to those values on every row. As the rectangle is always at Grid.Row=0 in the row template.

Comment: updated answer. I think it may be best to not use the rectangle, and instead focus on the datagrid row properties. this code should work although you will need to add a better trigger property. ideally Value!= "0", but of course xaml wont compile it then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/793966/1074345 should help you with that part.