# How to give the ListViewItem ToolTip precedence over the TextBlock ToolTip?

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, textblock, listviewitem

Given an object such as:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Simply displayed as:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- style stuff -->
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView 
        x:Name="ItemsListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Width="75"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="Foo"/>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Width="75"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="Bar"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In the `Grid.Resources` I created the following style to allow a `ToolTip` to display each *cell* value on hover:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter 
        Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=Text}"/>
    <Setter
        Property="TextTrimming"
        Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
</Style>
```

That works as desired. But now I want to validate a row based on the `Hidden` property. If the value is `-1`, outline the row in red and display a `TooTip` message:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Hidden}"
            Value="-1">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Bad Item... Bad!"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

That also works, *as long as I'm hovering over the cell borders* of the invalid item. The moment I hover over the `Foo` or `Bar` cell of the invalid item, the previous `ToolTip` displaying the cell value is shown.

[image: gif of current working code]

**How can I get the `ListViewItem.ToolTip` to override the `TextBlock.ToolTip` when the row is invalid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TextBlock style as follows so that ToolTip will be set in DataTrigger for specified condition. In this case, if ToolTip is not set on GridViewColumn then ListViewItem tooltip will appear automatically.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter
        Property="TextTrimming"
        Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding Hidden}"
            Value="0">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=Text}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly, except it only works for `Hidden==0` but should work for `Hidden > -1`.

Comment: You can't put a data trigger for greater than clause. So, you can try using Converter which will convert the Hidden property value to a Boolean flag to apply the setter in data trigger.

Comment: Yes, just found the same suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/793966/3773066). Thanks for your help.